# Secondary trackpad/mousepad button not functioning as expected

Tags: release-juno, touchpad

I've been using elementary OS on various computers for years.
I recently upgraded my travel laptop from a lower end unit (Lenovo N-22, Celeron, 4GB) to something with a bit more capability (Lenovo 11e, i3, 8GB).

Unfortunately, on this unit both elementary and Ubuntu treat the secondary trackpad/mousepad button the same as the primary button.  While a two-finger tap does function as the secondary button, it's not the same experience.
Oddly, the button works as expected on Zorin, Deepin and Wind*ws, so it's not a hardware issue.

I've read that things can get dicey on trackpads where the buttons are part of the general pad surface.  I've installed `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` but that has not made any difference.

If anyone has any driver or configuration suggestions then I'm all ears.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

**Update 1:**
I have just re-tried System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Touchpad -> Physical clicking -> Hardware default

The issue persists.

**Update 2:**
As requested, here is the output of: `apt list --installed | grep "xserver-xorg-input-libinput"`

```
xserver-xorg-input-libinput/bionic,now 0.27.1-1 amd64 [installed]
```

**Update 3:**

After installing `gnome-tweak-tool` and the selecting "Area under Mouse Click Emulation" Mouse Click Emulation option there is no change in behavior. Clicking the lower right button area of the trackpad is still treated as if the primary button is pushed. This behavior continued following a system reboot.

Comment: I have just re-tried System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Touchpad -> Physical clicking -> Hardware default

The issue persists.

Comment: Please update your question with the execution result / output of `apt list --installed | grep "xserver-xorg-input-libinput"`. Simply edit your question with what you see after executing this command in terminal.

Comment: If you don't see anything after executing the command from my earlier comment, please execute `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput` and let me know if this fix your issue.

Comment: Please install `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` via terminal and go to *Keyboard and Mouse* sub-menu. After that please select the option **Area** under *Mouse Click Emulation*. Please let me know what you find.

Comment: I see. Please add how you solved problem as answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: I thought I did. I removed a previously installed  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package and then the gnome-tweaks worked as advertised.

Comment: Yes, please add your solution as *Answer* by posting using the box followed by **Post your answer** in the bottom / down-side of the page.

Comment: Same issue here, also with a Lenovo (T450s). `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` is installed. Did install the `gnome-tweak-tool` and changed the config, without success. :( Any other hint? I am willing to report the solution once fixed :-D

Comment: BTW it stopped working recently, before that it used to work.

Answer (score 1):

In System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Touchpad tab, make sure that Physical Clicking is switched on and set to Default Hardware.

Comment: Your contribution is much appreciated, However, please always try to add more information about what to do and *why* to do. This is will be more helpful understanding the solution and the problem.

Comment: a) I don't see how can "add more information about what to do", as long as you have eyes you'll be able to follow.
b) I cannot go into technical details on "why" because I don't know them. Should I then refer myself from posting if I know the answer to the problem but not completely understand the technical background?

Comment: So you're saying that if I don't know the reason behind why "default hardware" will work I should not help at all. Is that correct?

Comment: I understand your point. But I also mentioned **why** and I *think* it will be more helpful for OP why they re following the steps. For example, why "make sure that Physical Clicking is switched on and set to Default Hardware" and why not "touchpad areas" or "multi-touch". Just a matter of making the answer as detailed as possible. **No, as a user you are always welcomed to ask questions and answer**. Perhaps someone who know will improve the answer. Thats how the network works. Please don't get me wrong.

Comment: I know that I'm welcomed, and I know that someone could add clarity to my post, but you're avoiding answering my question - if I don't know the reason behind why "default hardware" will work I should not help at all?

Comment: My intention was not rude and I am **not saying** that you shouldn't answer if you don't know the background. Its just a *suggestion to improve* the answer.

Comment: Please do not delete answer that can provide solution to a problem. If it is because my comment, I am really sorry. Please don't get me wrong.